Drop labels of a metric not entire job
I am new to Prometheus and relabeling. I am working with a job 'A' which has a lot of metrics and one of these metrics 'B' has 150 labels. Of these 150 labels I only want to keep 3 (D,E,F) and drop the rest. But I want to make sure that my relabeling rule only affects this one metric series 'B' and not the entire job.
How can I achieve this?
I tried drop and labeldrop but they affect the whole series or job.

An important detail of Prometheus metrics is that metric "names" are labels too. In fact, there's no distinction between metric names and labels. There's some "sugar" that makes the special label __name__ appears as metric names. For this reason the query {__name__=~".+"} can be used to limit all (scraped) metrics (=~ is the regex matcher and .+ for non-empty names). And so, {__name__="B", job="A"} form the base of your relabel.

There's also a useful Relabeler test tool online.
